# Filter Blocked Dates XSLT

Tags: xslt, filter, nodes

Have the following **input**

```
Sample Input : 

<GetShippingTimeSlotsRes xmlns:xsdLocal="example.com/xml/ShippingTimeSlotsRes" xmlns="example.com/xml/ShippingTimeSlotsRes">
    <xsdLocal:GetShippingTimeSlotsRes>
        <xsdLocal:Weekdate>04/24/2017</xsdLocal:Weekdate>
        <xsdLocal:Weekday>1</xsdLocal:Weekday>
        <xsdLocal:Category>2</xsdLocal:Category>
        <xsdLocal:From>08:00</xsdLocal:From>
        <xsdLocal:To>18:00</xsdLocal:To>
        <xsdLocal:AvailabilityId>1</xsdLocal:AvailabilityId>
        <xsdLocal:Sequence>2</xsdLocal:Sequence>
    </xsdLocal:GetShippingTimeSlotsRes>
    <xsdLocal:GetShippingTimeSlotsRes>
        <xsdLocal:Weekdate>04/25/2017</xsdLocal:Weekdate>
        <xsdLocal:Weekday>3</xsdLocal:Weekday>
        <xsdLocal:Category>3</xsdLocal:Category>
        <xsdLocal:From>13:00</xsdLocal:From>
        <xsdLocal:To>18:00</xsdLocal:To>
        <xsdLocal:AvailabilityId>1</xsdLocal:AvailabilityId>
        <xsdLocal:Sequence>123</xsdLocal:Sequence>
    </xsdLocal:GetShippingTimeSlotsRes>
    <xsdLocal:GetShippingTimeSlotsRes>
        <xsdLocal:Weekdate>04/26/2017</xsdLocal:Weekdate>
        <xsdLocal:Weekday>3</xsdLocal:Weekday>
        <xsdLocal:Category>3</xsdLocal:Category>
        <xsdLocal:From>13:00</xsdLocal:From>
        <xsdLocal:To>18:00</xsdLocal:To>
        <xsdLocal:AvailabilityId>1</xsdLocal:AvailabilityId>
        <xsdLocal:Sequence>123</xsdLocal:Sequence>
    </xsdLocal:GetShippingTimeSlotsRes>
    <xsdLocal:GetShippingTimeSlotsRes>
        <xsdLocal:Weekdate>04/27/2017</xsdLocal:Weekdate>
        <xsdLocal:Weekday>3</xsdLocal:Weekday>
        <xsdLocal:Category>3</xsdLocal:Category>
        <xsdLocal:From>13:00</xsdLocal:From>
        <xsdLocal:To>18:00</xsdLocal:To>
        <xsdLocal:AvailabilityId>1</xsdLocal:AvailabilityId>
        <xsdLocal:Sequence>123</xsdLocal:Sequence>
    </xsdLocal:GetShippingTimeSlotsRes>
    <xsdLocal:GetShippingTimeSlotsRes>
        <xsdLocal:Weekdate>04/28/2017</xsdLocal:Weekdate>
        <xsdLocal:Weekday>3</xsdLocal:Weekday>
        <xsdLocal:Category>6</xsdLocal:Category>
        <xsdLocal:From>18:00</xsdLocal:From>
        <xsdLocal:To>22:00</xsdLocal:To>
        <xsdLocal:AvailabilityId>1</xsdLocal:AvailabilityId>
        <xsdLocal:Sequence>123</xsdLocal:Sequence>
    </xsdLocal:GetShippingTimeSlotsRes>
    <xsdLocal:BlockedDates>
        <xsdLocal:Date>04/24/2017</xsdLocal:Date>
    </xsdLocal:BlockedDates>
    <xsdLocal:BlockedDates>
        <xsdLocal:Date>04/27/2017</xsdLocal:Date>
    </xsdLocal:BlockedDates>
</GetShippingTimeSlotsRes>
```

Sample Output :

```
<GetShippingTimeSlotsRes xmlns:xsdLocal="example.com/xml/ShippingTimeSlotsRes" xmlns="example.com/xml/ShippingTimeSlotsRes">
    <xsdLocal:GetShippingTimeSlotsRes>
        <xsdLocal:Weekdate>04/25/2017</xsdLocal:Weekdate>
        <xsdLocal:Weekday>3</xsdLocal:Weekday>
        <xsdLocal:Category>3</xsdLocal:Category>
        <xsdLocal:From>13:00</xsdLocal:From>
        <xsdLocal:To>18:00</xsdLocal:To>
        <xsdLocal:AvailabilityId>1</xsdLocal:AvailabilityId>
        <xsdLocal:Sequence>123</xsdLocal:Sequence>
    </xsdLocal:GetShippingTimeSlotsRes>
    <xsdLocal:GetShippingTimeSlotsRes>
        <xsdLocal:Weekdate>04/26/2017</xsdLocal:Weekdate>
        <xsdLocal:Weekday>3</xsdLocal:Weekday>
        <xsdLocal:Category>3</xsdLocal:Category>
        <xsdLocal:From>13:00</xsdLocal:From>
        <xsdLocal:To>18:00</xsdLocal:To>
        <xsdLocal:AvailabilityId>1</xsdLocal:AvailabilityId>
        <xsdLocal:Sequence>123</xsdLocal:Sequence>
    </xsdLocal:GetShippingTimeSlotsRes>
    <xsdLocal:GetShippingTimeSlotsRes>
        <xsdLocal:Weekdate>04/28/2017</xsdLocal:Weekdate>
        <xsdLocal:Weekday>3</xsdLocal:Weekday>
        <xsdLocal:Category>6</xsdLocal:Category>
        <xsdLocal:From>18:00</xsdLocal:From>
        <xsdLocal:To>22:00</xsdLocal:To>
        <xsdLocal:AvailabilityId>1</xsdLocal:AvailabilityId>
        <xsdLocal:Sequence>123</xsdLocal:Sequence>
    </xsdLocal:GetShippingTimeSlotsRes>
    <xsdLocal:BlockedDates>
        <xsdLocal:Date>04/24/2017</xsdLocal:Date>
    </xsdLocal:BlockedDates>
    <xsdLocal:BlockedDates>
        <xsdLocal:Date>04/27/2017</xsdLocal:Date>
    </xsdLocal:BlockedDates>
</GetShippingTimeSlotsRes>
```

Input comprises of **2 parts**

1) List of dates with time slots 
2) List of blocked dates

Time slots related to the dates which are blocked have to be filtered based on the dates which are present below.

Tried multiple approaches but none seems to work.

In the example shown above 24th and 27th april 2017 are shown as blocked dates and in the output there shouldnt be any node "xsdLocal:GetShippingTimeSlotsRes" which has the weekdate matching to those dates

Any help please?

Comment: **1.** What exactly does "filter" mean in this context? Please show the expected output of the given example. **2.** "*Tried multiple approaches but none seems to work.*" Post your best attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: There are a list of blocked dates present in the XML shown above i.e. 04.24.2017,05/01/2017. Also there is a repeating node GetShippingTimeSlotsRes which has a date called "WeekDate" in it. Expectation in response is that there shouldnt be any node "GetShippingTimeSlotsRes " which has the "WeekDate" as date present in one of the blocked dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the XSLT version, so I used version 2.0.

The whole thing boils down to creation of a template which matches
the items (time slots) which **are** in the "forbidden" list and
does nothing with them.

The remaining time slots (and other content) will be output by
the identity template.

How to create this template:

- Create a key for the blocked dates (at the beginning).
- Include a reference to this key in the *select* attribute of this
  "do-nothing" template.

A weird point in your XML is that your root *GetShippingTimeSlotsRes* tag
has the same name as the subordinate *GetShippingTimeSlotsRes* tag.

To refer to the **subordinate** tags only, I included *GetShippingTimeSlotsRes*
twice in the match attribute.

Below you have a working solution, as you see, quite short.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xsdLocal="example.com/xml/ShippingTimeSlotsRes"
  xpath-default-namespace="example.com/xml/ShippingTimeSlotsRes">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:key name="dates" match="BlockedDates/Date" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="GetShippingTimeSlotsRes/GetShippingTimeSlotsRes[key('dates',Weekdate)]"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```